# Обработка запроса в SQLITE3 и telebot

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, sqlite, telebot

Есть кусок кода, который создает новую таблицу в бд, бот в ответ на сообщение запроса добавления новой темы выводит текст "Введите вашу тему:", и следующее сообщение, которое напишет пользователь должен проверить на существование, если существует то вывести сообщение, если нет, то занести в бд, но он этого не делает. Ошибок никаких не выдает. Ощущение что он просто не видит чего-то. Таблицу создает, с этим все нормально, но не заносит новую тему

```
 if(message.text == "Задать новую тему"):
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS client_tema(
    tema TEXT
    )""")
    connect.commit()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите новую тему:")



    # Проверка на существования темы в бд
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    def newtema(message):
        people_tema = message.text
        cursor.execute(f"SELECT tema FROM client_tema WHERE tema = {people_tema}")
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        if data is None:
            # Добавление темы в поля
            users_tema = message.text
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO client_tema VALUES(?);", users_tema)
            connect.commit()
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Добавлена новая тема")
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Такая тема уже существует")
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Заметил некоторые проблемы с работой драйвером SQL.

1. Замените:

   ```
   cursor.execute(f"SELECT tema FROM client_tema WHERE tema = {people_tema}")
   ```

   На

   ```
   cursor.execute(f"SELECT tema FROM client_tema WHERE tema = ?", (people_tema,))
   ```
2. Замените:

   ```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO client_tema VALUES(?);", users_tema)
   ```

   На

   ```
   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO client_tema (tema) VALUES (?);", (users_tema,))
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, подправил. Делаю такие ошибки т.к только начал работу с бд. 
Но все так же ничего не происходит -_-

Comment: Сообщения от бота выводятся? Т.е. вы уверены, что код для работы с базой данных вызывается?

Comment: Выводится сообщение "Введите новую тему". Так же в файле бд создается таблица client_tema и столбец tema, но он пустой, то есть на то что я пишу в бота после его просьбы ввести новую тему он никак не реагирует, не выводит сообщения о том создана тема или уже существует,с и не прописывает ее в файл бд

Comment: т.е код перестает работать с строчки
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

Comment: Значит нужно разобраться почему не обрабатывается `@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) def newtema(message):`. Кст, в телеботе ведь есть функция планирования функции, которая вызывается следующей - `register_next_step_handler`? Вам скорее всего ее нужно вызывать и передавать `newtema`, чтобы после ввода юзера вызвалась именно она.

Comment: Ну почему не обрабатывается '@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"]) def newtema(message):'  я понять не могу. Уже пару часов на это убил. Про 'register_next_step_handler' почитаю, спасибо за совет. Если вдруг захотите, то можете глянуть весь код, мб что-то прояснится [Ссылка на гит](https://github.com/MaloyMeee/testtelegbd)

Comment: @Azazloqi, не, спасибо, лучше добавьте минимальный код в сам вопрос, это, кст, одно из рекомендаций по составлению вопросов :) Вангую, что код с `if(message.text == "Задать новую тему"):` вызывается в функции с декоратором `@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])`, тогда это объясняет. Эти декораторы же обработчики и если у вас 2 одинаковых обработчика, то скорее всего вызываться будет первый

Comment: да, декоратора действительно 2, но без добавления второго, который мы и рассматриваем я фиг знает как сделать :D

Comment: @Azazloqi, можно сделать состояния и запоминать их для каждого юзера, попробуйте через `register_next_step_handler`